# How to specify package version in package.xml or rosdep depends.yaml

Tags: ros, rosdep, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to make sure that a specific version of a system package is installed for my ros package.

Let's assume, that I want to make sure, that my rospackage `rpkg` requires the system dependency `foo` in version 3.4.  I thus want to have `foo` in version 3.4 installed when I run `rosdep update && rosdep install`.

I could either include that in the `package.xml` for that package (e.g. something like `<depends>foo:3.4</depends>`), but I don't know how.

I could otherwise include that in the `depends.yaml` (e.g. something like

```
foo:
  ubuntu: foo=3.4
```

) but again I don't know how :-(

I know, that it's possible to require/check the version in the `CMakeLists.txt`, but that is not what I want.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254811/how-to-specify-package-version-in-package.xml-or-rosdep-depends.yaml/) by [Michael Kopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/27206/michael-kopp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see if #q207735 answers your question.

Note btw that version info is currently not used by `rosdep` and friends. It's only used when generating binary packages (such as `deb`s and `rpm`s) on the buildfarm to resolve dependencies.

As far as I know there is currently no way to get `rosdep` to install specific versions.

As you write, the `find_package(..)` calls can require specific versions in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

PS: `depends.yaml` is a rather old piece of infrastructure. I'm not sure that is still universally supported these days.

---

Edit:

> Could you give me some more pointers about your comment about `depends.yaml`?  We use a `10-custom.list` file in `/etc/ros/rosde/sources.list.d` and this points to a `yaml our_server/depends.yaml` which defines packages we provide locally.  Is that a bad practice?

That is something else. From your comment I understand that you were distributing a `yaml` file with some extra depends *with your sources* (ie: as a sibling to `package.xml`). That is something that is / was actually possible, but I haven't seen it done much more these days.

What you are doing is essentially a locally extended `rosdep` db. That is perfectly fine, as long as you understand and accept that those dependencies will not be resolvable by people that don't have access to your extension.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michael Kopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/27206/michael-kopp/) on 2017-02-17**:
I see.  Thank you for your answer.  For other people directed to this question, see also this
[rosdep issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/325).

Do you see any other way with the ros toolchain to do what I want?

**Comment by [Michael Kopp](https://answers.ros.org/users/27206/michael-kopp/) on 2017-02-17**:
Could you give me some more pointers about your comment about `depends.yaml`?  We use a `10-custom.list` file in `/etc/ros/rosde/sources.list.d` and this points to a `yaml our_server/depends.yaml` which defines packages we provide locally.  Is that a bad practice?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-17**:\

> Do you see any other way with the ros toolchain to do what I want?

well, you can express the requirement in your `CMakeLists.txt`, but there's no way to get `rosdep` to check it for you unfortunately :( (that I know of. I would like to be proven wrong).